# Use hdbuserstore with Java application

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

How can I connect to HANA DB using the credentials stored in hdbuserstore?

In the [SAP docs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/2.9/en-US/1c86038c05464d31a7dcae14f2d8a7dd.html), inorder to connect using jdbc driver, 3 methods are mentioned:

- `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)`

  Ex:

  ```
  java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
      ("jdbc:sap://localhost/?instanceNumber=00&databaseName=tdb1",
          "SYSTEM", "manager");
  ```
- `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url)`

  Ex:

  ```
  java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection                            
      ("jdbc:sap://localhost:30013/?databaseName=tdb1&user=SYSTEM&password=manager");
  ```
- `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)`

  Ex:

  ```
  java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
  info.put("databaseName", "tdb1");
  info.put("user", "SYSTEM");
  info.put("password", "manager");
  java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://localhost:30013", info);
  ```

I am not able to figure out how I can conenct to HANA DB using hdbuserstore key with this driver. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Did you check the section "JDBC Connection Properties"? There is a connection property called "key". Also found an example for it: https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-jdbc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `key`(which specifies the key for the hdbuserstore) JDBC property.

Say your hdbuserstore entry is:

```
hdbuserstore SET JOHN_DOE "127.0.0.1:35001@DB" dbUserName dbPassword
```

You can connect using:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver; 
public class Demo  {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {  
            java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
            // key mentioned in hdbuserstore
            info.put("key", "JOHN_DOE");
            connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://127.0.0.1:35001", info);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            // .... whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Check out SAP JDBC properties list [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.03/en-US/109397c2206a4ab2a5386d494f4cf75e.html).